# How to remove element from array after uncheck of checkbox

Tags: javascript, reactjs, checkbox

I am having multiple locations, on check of the particular location i can able to push those into array on check of checkbox unable to remove from array

```
handleChange(e){
    if(e.target.checked){
        let selectedLocations = this.state.selectedLocations;
        selectedLocations.push({
            name: e.target.name,
            isActive: true
        });
        this.setState({
            selectedLocations: selectedLocations
        });
    }else{
        let selectedLocations = this.state.selectedLocations;

    }


}

{
 locations && locations.map((el, i) => {
   return (
         <div className="col-md-4">
         <div className="form-group">
         <input type="checkbox" value="true"  name={el.name} onChange={this.handleChange.bind(this)}/><label> &nbsp;{el.name} </label>
      </div>
  </div>
 )
})
}
```

I want to remove from array after unchecking particular location

Comment: you have set a state in else condition, since you are using same `selectedLocations`  ur result gets unchanged, also you need to consider `locations` should be updated in sync with `selectedLocations`, I assume because you have not posted the complete code.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't try to mutate the state by pushing directly to state. I would suggest try something similar like below

```js
handleChange(e){
    if(e.target.checked){
        this.setState(({selectedLocations}) => ({
            selectedLocations: [...selectedLocations, {
            name: e.target.name,
            isActive: true
        }]
        }));
    } else {
        this.setState(({selectedLocations}) => ({
            selectedLocations: selectedLocations.filter((element) =>  (e.target.name !== element.name))
        }));
    }
}
```

Comment: this is what my answer would be, except there are just a couple of issues (which I assume are just from overlooking when copy pasting): the `const selectedLocations...` will not be available in the `else` block. Also, I believe it would be better practice to use the callback syntax inside `setState` instead of setting a `const` from state. (that is:
`this.setState(({selectedLocations}) => ({ selectedLocations:selectedLocations.filter((element) =>  (e.target.name !== element.name))}));`

and same idea for the first `setState`

)

Answer (score 0):

Try to pass map index with function and split that index value from an array.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.filter()`. I'm assuming that the `name` property is unique but you can also store a key to be more precise:

```
this.setState({
  selectedLocations: selectedLocations.filter(l => l.name !== e.target.name)
});
```

Comment: @Nathanael,  I think answer should be updated to l.name !== e.target.name. The person who downvoted didn't bother to correct you I believe :).

Answer (score 0):

Use lodash remove function

```
handleCheckboxChange = (e, id) => {
  const { selected_ids } = this.props;
  let updated_selected_ids = [];
  if (e.target.checked) {
    updated_selected_ids = selected_ids.concat([id]);
  } else {
    updated_selected_ids = remove(selected_ids, n => n !== id);
  }
}
```

If you don't want to use lodash you can use [filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) method as well.

```
handleCheckboxChange = (e, id) => {
  const { selected_ids } = this.props;
  let updated_selected_ids = [];
  if (e.target.checked) {
   updated_selected_ids = selected_ids.concat([id]);
 } else {
   updated_selected_ids = selected_ids.filter(function(n){ return n !== id })
}
```